# Bootstrap form-inline button width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make button the same width as inputs:

[image]

My html code:

```
<form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="category" placeholder="Категория"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Город"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="when" placeholder="На этой неделе"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Найти</a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add padding to the button like this--

```
.btn-lg {
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
    }
```

Change the values according to your need.

Comment: It works, but I need the same responsive width as inputs have

Comment: give the values in %. that will make it responsive..I don't think bootstrap has any custom class for this perticular work

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply custom styles at the different sizes. You can use the CSS below as a starting point for making buttons the same width in responsive way.

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
}

/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
}
```

For example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .btn {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

You should determine different size for every media.